# How may I display 'loading' text onChangeMonthYear in the JQueryUI DatePicker control?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

The JQueryUI datepicker control has an onChangeMonthYear method that calls a REST based service to fetch dates.  The service takes some time to return dates to the UI and the calendar appears to hang for a approx. two seconds before switching to the new month.

I would like to have some type of 'loading...' text or spinner graphic displayed while the service is being called and working on returning data.

I tried setting a label to be displayed during the call by using $("#checkingAvailability").show();  However, the UI is not updated until after the data is returned.

What I really need to do is hide the calendar control and display the 'loading...' label or graphic while the REST based service is working on returning data, and then show the calendar again once the result is succesful.

Can anyone point me in the right direction or offer some sample code?  I'm am stumped.

Comment: This can be triggered and removed in your AJAX callbacks. Then it's simply a matter of revealing and hiding a item in the Widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the changing nature of the DatePicler Widget, you might consider making a loading gif and shade that can unhidden or brought into view as needed. As I cannot replicate your example, that is not provided, I can provide an example like this.

```js
$(function() {

  function makeLoader(cnt, img) {
    return $("<div>", {
        class: "ui-datepicker-loading"
      })
      .css({
        background: "rgba(0,0,0,0.65)",
        width: "272px",
        height: "224px",
        "border-radius": "3px",
        color: "white",
        "text-align": "center"
      })
      .html("<p style='padding-top: 100px'>" + cnt + "</p><img width='20' src='" + img + "'></img>")
      .appendTo("body")
      .hide();
  }

  function showLoader(tObj) {
    $(".ui-datepicker-loading").show().position({
      my: "left top",
      at: "left+3 top+3",
      of: tObj
    }).css("z-index", 1001);
  }

  function hideLoader() {
    $(".ui-datepicker-loading").hide().position({
      my: "left top",
      at: "left-300 top-300",
      of: $("body")
    }).css("z-index", 0);
  }

  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    onChangeMonthYear: function(yy, mm, dp) {
      showLoader($(this).datepicker("widget"));
      setTimeout(hideLoader, 2000);
    }
  });
  var l = makeLoader("Getting dates...", "https://i.gifer.com/ZKZg.gif");
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
```

When the callback is first called, we show the loading elements. Once the Data is gathered, we can then hide it.

Comment: Thanks for the sample code.  One issue i'm bumping into is the loading spinner/text does not appear above the calenar, but in the top left corner of my form.  I assume this is becuase we're appending to the body.  However, i've tried appending to the textbox without any success.  Is there an easy way to make sure the spinner follows the calendar and overlays it regardless of the form's makeup?

Comment: @Zoop Please provide a minimal example of the issue.